#  count is wrong in "More to go" for comments

Tags: bug, comments, unicode

When you go to add a comment, the text incorrectly reads:

```
enter at least 15 characters
```

However, it does not enforce this, as only 8 characters are required. This can be readily demonstrated by adding a  character one at a time.

```
   Characters  Message                       String
   ----------  --------------                -----------
            0  enter at least 15 characters
            1  13 more to go...              
            2  11 more to go...              
            3  9 more to go...               
            4  7 more to go...               
            5  5 more to go...               
            6  3 more to go...               
            7  1 more to go...               
            8  584 characters left           
            9  582 characters left           
           10  580 characters left
```

The bug is that the code is **not counting characters** — Unicode code points — but merely some sort of tetranibble artifact of UTF-16 being mishandled as UCS-2.

Like UTF-8, UTF-16 is a variable-width encoding. The code needs to be updated to give accurate counts for actual characters. Nobody should have to know about tetranibbles, or believe lies about needing to enter 15 characters when entering just 8 characters is provably sufficient.

Comment: 

Comment: You're right! 

Comment: There are so many more problems with the comment restrictions in general that I barely even read this one when I saw what you were complaining about. :) (omg dat resetting timer!!!)

Comment: darn... couldn't stop myself, it's true 

Comment: Orange you glad I didn't... wait...

Comment: Wow - this is really *fruity*, and we should certainly *peel* such things from the char count! We would be *bananas* not to, and might look like we're being *yellow* to not enforce this. It *Musa* be fixed *berry* quickly!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @AlexM., q̊q̊q̊q̊q̊q̊q̊q̊ also works. And many others. See my answer.

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: +1 just for the art, actually it's really too minor to be worth the amount of time needed to fix. So we'll have more useless comments, not the end of the world.

Comment: @Pacerier k  

Comment: Seriously why do you care so much about this? In your mind, mentally read "characters" not as the meaning you have arbitrarily chosen and assumed to be the intention, but instead as one of its other meanings (hint: there are _loads_ of them). Then you won't have a problem. And you can go do something actually useful with your day.

Comment: Up vote from me for the banana in the title - it was the only reason I read your question. Then another +1 for *tetranibbles*. But also -1 for every fruit I'm going to have to edit out of titles now that you've started it.

Comment: What I'm now trying to figure out is if this is serious or fun...

Comment: @Won't Notice the funny goobers that snuck in between some of your s. That's a bug, too: it makes them very unappetizing. After all, who knows where those goobers came from? They might even be contagious.

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Short commentz rulez !

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ^ I never considered using ZWSP to get around restrictions on minimum comment length.

Comment: ^^^^ Only 300 bananas can be inserted in a comment, not 600.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος This is because each banana code point costs 2 UTF-16 code units, which is all they're counting here. (It costs 4 UTF-8 code units for display purposes.) They are (rather curiously) calling code units not code points “characters”; hence the disparity here.

Comment: @tchrist Believe me you cannot stick 301 bananas in a comment!

Comment: A "banana" is 6 characters and "2 bananas" are 9 characters. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since comments have to be stored in the database as [`nvarchar(600)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) the current behavior accurately measures the remaining number of . . .  something. Thanks to [UCS-2 and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805259/storing-utf-16-unicode-data-in-sql-server)'s definition of the `len()` function, [300 bananas has a length of 600](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/307984/thats-a-bunch-of-bananas?opt.textResults=true), so the count is accurate in terms of what we'll be able to store. The problem here is terminology and the element of surprise that some characters use more of the quota than others.

The simplest solution to the terminology problem would be to leave out the word "characters":

```
   Characters  Message                       String
   ----------  --------------                -----------
            0  enter at least 15
            1  13 more to go...              
            2  11 more to go...              
            3  9 more to go...               
            4  7 more to go...               
            5  5 more to go...               
            6  3 more to go...               
            7  1 more to go...               
            8  584 left                      
            9  582 left                      
           10  580 left
```

Yes, it's a bit strange to see your counter go down by two when you've only entered one character. On the other hand, most comments on English-language sites won't have longer characters, such as the [banana](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm). For most comments, there won't be any difference between the number of characters remaining and the count displayed.

While researching how other sites manage this problem, I noticed that Twitter accurately counts the number of bananas:

[image: Twitter counts bananas]

Ideally, we'd do the same thing. But in order to do that, the database field would need to be sized to correctly hold all possible comments. I believe that can be accomplished by using [supplementary character collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726(v=sql.110).aspx#Supplementary_Characters). The change should be easy enough, but *testing* the change and not breaking other parts of the system will not be trivial. And, of course, the countdown display would need to be adjusted as well. None of this seems worth the hassle on English-language sites, but it could very well be somewhat more important on [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable to just stop mentioning characters. I was thinking that there might be some database issue here. For my work we use UTF-8 storage; I didn’t know anyone still used the old UCS-2; it takes so much space! Good call about there being more important Unicode problems to worry about for the Japanese site. With all the East_Asian_Width=Wide characters throwing off notions of what fits where, plus the U+3099 and U+309A combining Kana voice marks that must not be split, things are definitely trickier than on an English-language site. Good luck with that, and thank you.

Comment: This is bananas.

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug with the char-handling **only if** we assume that they had actually wanted to count Unicode codepoints. But would fixing the code to count Unicode codepoints solve the problem that characters don't match users' expectations?

No, because **even after** fixing codepoints, and assuming that everything is perfect and "bug-free", Unicode considers `q̊q̊q̊` to be 6 codepoints, whereas it is really only 3 *user-perceived characters*.

So perhaps, the "bug" or problem here is that we are using Unicode. Unicode codepoints **do not** map directly (one codepoint for each *user-perceived character*) onto the writing systems taught in schools, because Unicode claims that [it's *too hard* to do so for all languages](http://goo.gl/8IKoP7). As such, a *user-perceived character* is **not** the same as Unicode codepoint.

The easiest solution would be to ignore the problem. Users are already used to "weird behavior" for characters outside the so-called "English range". No one's going to be too surprised.

The easier solution is to change the message from *"10 characters left"* to *"10 Unicode codepoints left"*. (Needless to say, this kind of information is pretty useless to users.) Another easy solution is to convey a vague message, e.g. *"about 10 characters left"*. (Like how Google Search [often gives a vague estimate](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/google-counts-may-not-be-as-reliable-as-you-imagine).)

The (extremely) hard but **proper** solution will be to allow users to enter only *user-perceived characters*. This is basically **white-listing** every character that's going to be supported, as opposed to blacklisting anomalies one by one. For example:

- If the use case is to accept English written language, the white-list will accept only the characters `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`. Probably adding more if needed (`.`, `,`, `(`, `)`, `!`, `@`, etc) on a case-by-case basis. The white-list will prevent any chances for anomalies to happen.
- If the use case is to accept Japanese written language, the white-list will accept only the  [1006 + 1130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji) + [~40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) + [~40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana)  characters. Probably adding more if needed (e.g. supporting obsolete hiragana/katakana/kanji, and non-kanas like `『`, `〲`, `ゝ`, etc.) on a case-by-case basis.
- If the use case is to accept PRC Chinese written language, the white-list will accept only the [8105](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_General_Standard_Chinese_Characters) characters, probably adding more if needed on a case-by-case basis.
- And so on.

With pure white-listing, we can control every single input such that there would be no way for users to enter "weird" stuff like [emoji characters](http://getemoji.com) and etc.

Comment: [It gets worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert#comment831292_170970).

Comment: Why not count graphemes as user-perceived characters? They are well-defined formally so it is easy to code. That also solves the combining character bug in my "it gets worse" link above. This all reminds me of the [atomic character bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254013/unicode-mishandling-bug-in-chat-starboard-truncati%ef%bf%bd) at some level: splitting what you shouldn't, thanks to miscounting.

Comment: @tchrist, Do you mean "grapheme" as defined in [Unicode glossary](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#2), or "grapheme" in general according to graphemics? If you are talking about Unicode graphemes, then no, it wouldn't solve them problem because `z̐` is an invalid character; it simply doesn't exist in any "real" language, yet according to your method you would still consider it valid. Same for z͕͓͔̖̖̖̖̖̖̖̖̖̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜.

Comment: Pure **white-listing**  is the only solution as per mentioned above. But needless to say this is a "fantasy" problem no one can be bothered to solve. Which is why comments can always be as short as zero characters or as tall as one full p̴̵̶͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔̖͕͓̖̱̲̳̖̖̖̖̖̖̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̑̒̓̔̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜age .

Comment: @Pacerrier I don't know why you are talking about alphabets. That's a red herring. People can compose whatever ad hoc graphemes they wish. So of course I am talking about Unicode extended grapheme clusters. Those are open-ended by design.

Comment: @tchrist, You were talking about counting, which is why I raised those points about allocating user input into boxes (white-listing). With white-listing, you have a definite count.  How much count should we assign to "t̒͢ḧ́̚͡isͯ͜͜͜͜͜"? The user is going to count it as 4 because it is indeed really only 4 user-perceived characters. Is it right for the system to count it as 4?

Answer (score -5):

Actually the bug is that it says "characters" when it should say "bytes".

But that would be ridiculous.

I think everyone knows what the intent is here. Nothing to change.

Comment: How is it ridiculous? It's objectively wrong.

Comment: “Bytes”?  Like seriously? You seem to have misunderstood Unicode. Pray tell, just which byte were you planning on storing something like € in anyway? The byte 0xA4 for € works only in the ISO-8859-15 encoding — and down that road lies madness. That € takes 3 bytes in this web page’s UTF-8, so if you had your way it would be what, 3 less in the count? Nobody should be talking about bytes, especially when calling them characters, which they aren’t. Only actual logical characters should be mentioned, not incorrect counts related to low-level bit layouts used in this or that encoding system.

Comment: @tchrist, **Actual logical characters?** So who decides what's actual logical characters? Unicode is a solution to a problem, but it's [not perfect](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/124115/24257). Unicode characters map onto a language called the [Unicode language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription), they try to resemble [real-world languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) but they're only about as identical as twins are. Just look at my next comment, written in 15 Unicode "logical characters" but 0 real-world characters:

Comment: @Pacerier You do not count €  as three characters. It’s just one. No user cares that that is 24 bits. To the user it is one character, and that is all that matters. Classic programmer UX failure.

Comment: @tchrist, You do not count "͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏" as 15 characters. It's just zero. No use cares that that's 15 unicode characters. To the user it is zero letters, and that is all that matters. Classic [Unicode UX](http://goo.gl/8IKoP7) failure. ......... 2) This is not about encoding, because the layer **before** encoding is already flawed. The writing system provides an interface to the user through user-perceived characters. **These are called "letters"**, not characters. "characters" is merely an abstraction to make handling "letters" easier. No user cares about "characters".

Comment: @tchrist, Counting column-widths don't make sense for many languages, e.g. Arabic. What people learn in schools is called the writing system, and each language has [it's own writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems) though there are definitely similarities. The writing system is what Unicode should match. Not some arbitrary concept like "characters" which no user understands.

Comment: @tchrist: No, I have not "misunderstood Unicode". Conversely, you have misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Bytes aren't exactly correct either. "[The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)" We paper over that by reporting a number that theoretically means something to the user. Unfortunately UCS-2 is a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Comment: @JonEricson: That quote talks about a leaky abstraction; the 2 bytes are null termination, which quite rightly isn't included in SO's count of remaining available _bytes_ in the comment box. :)

Comment: The count below the comment box doesn't count bytes. It counts UTF-16 code units. Each character you type takes either two or four bytes in UTF-16.

Comment: @JonEricson, The leaky abstraction starts right from Unicode itself. It's supposed to map to writing systems used in living languages, but didn't managed to do it in a non-leaky way.