# Bad Request - Invalid URL with Unicode in URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, unicode, url-encoding

There is a question on the Ru.SO that can't be opened (at least for me under Chrome and Edge) with HTTP 400 error:

I have made a dumb question on Meta.SE to reproduce this.

[Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/)

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

[In case of edit, direct URL can be used.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/264085/edit)

I believe it's because a "�" character in the URL of the question and **the cyrillics**. Only appear if the title contain both cyrillics and this character.

Comment: huh! [reproduced on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/%EF%BF%BD-cause-a-problem-on-opening-question-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, it was me. :D I just edited an original question, so it can be actually answered.

Comment: Oddly enough, the link works fine on the mobile app.

Comment: @lxrec And why it shouldn't? I bet the mobile app didn't use the title as an URL and just request the title and body by API.

Comment: Looks like some sort of block in the IIS level to me

Comment: The direct link to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264085/ doesn't work either.

Comment: I wonder who managed to vote on it and where the views came from

Comment: "с кириллицей" == "with cyrillic" on Russian

Comment: @Lix it seems Ixrec could access it on their mobile... so probably him/her...

Comment: Too much high tech stuff... I'm getting dizzy

Comment: @Lix maybe someone used the API to upvote it

Comment: @durron597 because it cause a 301 header then redirect to the bad URL.

Comment: @ShadowWizard half answer: It's definitely not because of "�" character as I can open [another post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254013/254554)

Comment: @HackerKarma that's a different character. It just looks the same because the browser can't handle it. (in that post you now linked, where it's not crashing, it's some emoji as far as I remember)

Comment: @ShadowWizard man this bug is driving me crazy... I want to nail this but helpless due to server side code but one thing I can tell for sure is that it's a URL encoding issue

Comment: @Hack really better let the team handle this, and hopefully write a post-mortem report when it's all over.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Marc Gravell posted his [findings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/character-causes-a-problem-on-opening-question-with-cyrillics) and my hunch about 'encoding' was right.

Comment: @HackerKarma it isn't really the encoding as such; IIS (or something else in our stack) just seems to hate that codepoint - it isn't isolated.

Comment: @MarcGravell and ShadowWizard I take it back... So its' the IIS that doesn't like it... ahha. Thanks. And, now I feel like going after IIS to see why it hates that... I will do research in my spare time.

Answer (score -3):

Not 100% unviewable:

Use the API:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/264085?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta&filter=!0Uv6ZT)nwkwHYT3ON9gGlQ3gB
```

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "bug",
        "hyperlinks"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 442,
        "user_id": 186774,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d28147f1a035b2ddfc943edc98cd5e0f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
        "display_name": "m0nhawk",
        "link": "http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186774/m0nhawk"
      },
      "comment_count": 0,
      "close_vote_count": 0,
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 3,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "up_vote_count": 3,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "score": 3,
      "last_activity_date": 1440260151,
      "creation_date": 1440255100,
      "last_edit_date": 1440260151,
      "question_id": 264085,
      "link": "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/%ef%bf%bd-cause-a-problem-on-opening-question-with-cyrillics-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9",
      "title": "&#171;�&#187; cause a problem on opening question with cyrillics (с кириллицей)",
      "body": "<p>� sign cause a problem on accessing the question.</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n  <p>Bad Request - Invalid URL</p>\n  \n  <p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>\n</blockquote>\n"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9972
}
```

Or just plop it into the sandbox:

https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3867804#3867804

[image]

Comment: Uni what is this API output? You can get the same error under dev tools 'Network' status

Comment: @Hack what do you mean? But I just edited the answer, so is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I mean to say ur JSON output HTTP error code 400 Invalid URL

Comment: Uni, You're giving example of API call which returns the JSON data that one can parse and render which is working on mobile app already. Whereas, Meta.SE is making a HTTP (and not API call) request  here.

Comment: I don't see what purpose this answer serves. Yes, Stack Exchange API exists and is well documented. This has nothing to do with HTTP request failure.