# "�" causes a problem on opening question with cyrillics (с кириллицей)

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

� sign cause a problem on accessing the question.

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Comment: This question opens in the mobile android app, but not on the mobile theme in a browser

Comment: Yep, it sure does. Please don't put that back into the title while I fix it! I've edited at the database level to make this question available.

Comment: A way to test if this is fixed is following [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/%ef%bf%bd-causes-a-problem-on-opening-question-with-cyrillics-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9/)

Comment: @Braiam no, it isn't; the fundamental problem is outside of our part of the stack: we can't make IIS happier. What we can do, however, is to *not generate links that won't work*. Which is what is now the case. And in particular: to not *force a redirect* to a broken url. Hence why you can now view this question.

Comment: @Andy: I wondered how the question had five votes when my best URL hacking couldn't get it to display....

Comment: @MarcGravell then, why other web servers allow such combination? AFAIK, RFC 3986 allows any unreserved character using the percent-encoding method.

Comment: @Braiam because software often has glitches in a few edge cases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some Unicode combinations that [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) just hates and refuses to play with no matter how much you %-encode them. You seem to have found another one! Congrats.

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Marc, OP has posted another question about this. See [Bad Request - Invalid URL with Unicode in URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264084/bad-request-invalid-url-with-unicode-in-url?noredirect=1#comment859626_264084) which should be marked as [status-completed]

Comment: @HackerKarma thanks; commented and tagged, etc

Comment: Marc, posting in chat is appending the problematic character http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3886059#3886059

Comment: @Braiam no more dance?

Comment: @Braiam thanks - will merge the changes into chat tomorrow