# Is there any logical alternative for selecting username?

Tags: support, display-names

Some SE Philosophy users are using numbers for their user name. It is difficult to identify them. Now the number has become a 7 digit number [e.g. user1234567]. So, isn't it good if they use some names instead of a 7 digit number?

We can't distinguish user1234567 from user1235467 and **remember them quickly**.

Is there any **logical** alternative for selecting username by default to solve this issue?

Comment: Are the users grayed out and unlinked, by any chance?

Comment: You think that it becomes better if they name themselves [Alex](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/762191)?

Comment: Can you clarify more what you're talking about please?

Comment: *force* ... let's not do that ...

Comment: @rene: I am no end of gratified to discover that as of right now, that query shows exactly 1234 users with the name Anonymous.

Answer (score 8):

It's the default username. It increments since its the number *actually* is the same as the UID for the user on the site, and it keeps increment since there's *lots* of users.
We don't force users to pick a username (many do!) and it reduces the amount of friction for a new user.

[image: screenshot of user118150, with their user number circled on the URL bar and with an arrow pointing at their display name.]

Considering SE usernames are not unique, it can be less confusing in a few cases. You can probably distinguish them by the numbers ;p

Comment: ... and then there are a few users who intentionally pick a userxxxx number that isn't actually their UID.

Comment: ._. That way leads to chaos and anarchy.

Comment: @Catija true, and there are users who pick nonsense name, unclear name, and even [blank names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231838/certain-usernames-not-displaying-at-all). All by design, all allowed, and all is good. :)